# Change date and time format from csv file without using date -d

Tags: text-processing, date, csv

I have a *.csv* file contains

```
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
```

I want to change date and time format of column 3 as following:

From `10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM` (12-Hour) to `20171024 08:10:00`(24-hour).

Not using -d

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to use `date -d`?

Answer (score 5):

A pure awk solution (that doesn’t fork off a `date` command):

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '
function fail() {
        printf "Bad data at line %d: ", NR
        print
        next
    }
    {
        if (split($3, date_time, " ") != 3) fail()
        if (split(date_time[1], date, "/") != 3) fail()
        if (split(date_time[2], time, ":") != 3) fail()
        if (time[1] == 12) time[1] = 0
        if (date_time[3] == "PM") time[1] += 12
        $3 = sprintf("%.4d%.2d%.2d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d", date[3], date[1], date[2], time[1], time[2], time[3])
        print
    }'
```

- `-F'|'` breaks the input line apart at vertical bars
  into `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc…
- `split($3, date_time, " ")` breaks the date/time field into three pieces:
  the date, the time, and the AM/PM indicator. 
  If there aren’t three pieces, issue an error message and skip the line.
- `split(date_time[1], date, "/")` splits the date
  into the month, the day, and the year.
- `split(date_time[2], time, ":")` splits the time
  into the hour, the minutes, and the seconds.
- Do some math on the hour;
  for example, 12:42 AM is 00:42 in 24-hour time. 
  And of course PM adds 12 hours.
- The `sprintf` reassembles the year, month, day,
  hour, minutes, and seconds, with leading zeroes, if necessary. 
  Assigning this to `$3` rebuilds the input line
  with the reformatted date/time; we then print that.
- Feature: If the input has more than three fields; e.g.,

  ```
  Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM|Data4|Data5
  ```

  this script will preserve those extra field(s).

---

**Usage:** 
A few minor variations:

- Type the above multi-line command, and, at the end of the last line
  (right after `}'`), put the name(s) of file(s) you want to process. 
  You can (of course) use wildcards (e.g., `*.csv`) here,
  in addition to or instead of filename(s).
- Same as the above, but after `}'`, say **`<`** and a filename. 
  (You can process only one file at a time this way.)
- Create a script file.

  - The first line should be `#!/bin/sh`. 
    (Or, if you prefer, you can use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. 
    A discussion of the differences between these different “she-bang” lines,
    and their relative merits and counter-indications,
    is beyond the scope of this question,
    but you can find plenty of discourse on the topic if you search.)
  - Then put the above code starting at line 2.
  - At the end of the last line (right after `}'`), 
    put `"$@"` (***including*** the quotes).
  - Save the file. 
    Let’s assume that you call the script `gman`.
  - Type `chmod +x gman`.
  - Type `./gman` followed by either a list of filenames and/or wildcards,
    or by **`<`** and a single filename.

Comment: How to use this one sir? @G-Man

Comment: @JohnChristianDelaCruz:  See  above.

Comment: Can you see a screenshot sir @G-Man?

Comment: @JohnChristianDelaCruz:  What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it assuming `infile` is your CSV file:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='|'
while read data1 data2 datestr 
do
    newdatestr=$(date -d"$datestr" +"%Y%m%d %T")
    printf "%s|%s|%s\n" "$data1" "$data2" "$newdatestr"
done < infile
```

Answer (score 3):

with `AWK`:

save file `a.awk`:

```
BEGIN{
    FS="|"
    OFS = FS
}
{
    "date -d '"$3"' +'%Y%m%d %T' " | getline l
    $3 = l
    print $0
}
```

and run it with your csv file:

```
awk -f a.awk file.csv
```

for example, output is :

```
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:14:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:14:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:11:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:10:06
Data1|Data2|20171024 20:10:06
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:50
```

with this example:

```
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 PM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:14:00 PM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:11:00 PM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:06 PM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 PM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:50 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `perl` or any language with interface to `strptime()` and `strftime()`:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F'[|]' -lape '
  $F[2] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[2], "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")->
                       strftime("%Y%m%d %T");
  $_ = join "|", @F' < file.csv
```

Same with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
while IFS='|' read -rA F; do
  strftime -rs t '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' $F[3] &&
    strftime -s 'F[3]' '%Y%m%d %T' $t
  printf '%s\n' "${(j:|:)F}"
done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `date` (but not `date -d`) and a shell like `bash` that understands process substitutions:

```
$ cat file
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
Data1|Data2|10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
$ paste -d '|' <( cut -d '|' -f -2 file ) <( date -f <( cut -d '|' -f 3 file ) +'%Y%m%d %T' )
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:00
Data1|Data2|20171024 08:10:00
```

The call to `date` reads the dates from the `cut` command, which extracts the third `|`-delimited column from the given file. It outputs one reformatted date per line of input.

This is then pasted together with the first two columns using `paste`.

This has the downside that it reads the file twice, but it only calls `date` once (and without `-d`).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with `dateutils`, e.g. with the following input:

```
10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
10/24/2017 8:10:00 PM
10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
10/24/2017 8:14:00 PM
10/24/2017 8:10:00 AM
10/24/2017 8:11:00 PM
10/24/2017 8:10:06 PM
10/24/2017 8:10:00 PM
10/24/2017 8:10:50 AM
```

and the `dateconv` or `dateutils.dconv` program:

```
dateconv -i '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p' -f '%Y%m%d %T' < infile
```

Output:

```
20171024 08:10:00
20171024 20:10:00
20171024 08:10:00
20171024 20:14:00
20171024 08:10:00
20171024 20:11:00
20171024 20:10:06
20171024 20:10:00
20171024 08:10:50
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily done by using `sed`'s `extended regex`

I am amazed that no one has given answer using `sed`

`GNU sed`'s one liner :

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/\3\1\2/' file_name
```

Here I used extended regex to capture groups

Comment: You also need to translate the 08:00:00 AM to 20:00:00